# Show stepped area lines above columns in GViz

Tags: google-visualization

I have a chart I've created using GViz like so:
[image: Stepped Area and Column Chart]

It's a combo chart, with one series displayed as columns and the other displayed as a stepped area (0% opacity, connectSteps : false). I don't want to use line because that only does a dot in the middle of each column.

I'm trying to have the lines show above the columns because they represent a target amount. I've tried switching the order of the data columns, but it displayed the same way. Is there a way to specify z-index on series?

Side note: This is a chart on a Google Site, but by editing the HTML, I can specify most options available through GViz. I've already looked through the documentation but have not seen something to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to adjust the Z-axis on combo charts (so you can't do what you're trying to do in the way you're doing it).

However, if you want to be tricky, you can recreate the same sort of chart using XY scatter charts.

Example (copy-paste in to Google Playground):

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Targets');
        data.addRows([
          [1, 0, null],
          [1, 1, null],
          [1, null, null],
          [2, 0, null],
          [2, 3, null],
          [2, null, null],
          [3, 0, null],
          [3, 3, null],
          [3, null, null], 
          [0.5,null,1.5],
          [1.5,null,1.5],
          [1.5,null,null],    
          [1.5,null,2.5],
          [2.5,null,2.5],
          [2.5,null,null],    
          [2.5,null,3],
          [3.5,null,3],
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(
        document.getElementById('visualization'));
        chart.draw(data, {
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
          series: {0:{color: 'black', lineWidth: 40, pointSize: 0}, 1:{color: 'red', lineWidth: 10, pointSize: 0}}  });
      }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That would work, except my X-axis is strings for different categories. It's a good answer for anyone using numbers, though.

Comment: Well, there are a bunch of ways to add strings to my example, for instance by creating a secondary line or column graph with a min/max of zero, no data, and hidden axes/grid lines below it with the labels.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. I'll take a look next week after I release my current update.

Comment: I created an example of how to add fake labels to a chart [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194013/google-chart-how-to-draw-the-vertical-axis-for-linechart/14274651#14274651) Feel free to take a look if you want to see what sorts of tricks to use.