# Google Chart: How to draw the vertical axis for LineChart?

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I want to draw a Google's line chart in my web page! Here is my js code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1'],
    ['A',   1,       10],
    ['B',   2,       5],
    ['C',   4,       12],
    ['D',   8,       5]
  ]);

  var options = {
      curveType: 'function',
      lineWidth: 2,
      hAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'red', 
        textStyle: {color: '#000', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 10}, 
        gridlines: { color: '#f3f3f3', count: 5} 
      },
      vAxis: {
        baseline: 0, 
        viewWindowMode: "explicit", 
        viewWindow:{ min: 0 },
        gridlines: { color: '#f3f3f3', count: 6} 
      }
    };
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, options);
}
```

However, the result chart is drawing without any vertical axis line. How I can add the vertical axis lines as below images:
[image]
Thank you so much!

Comment: You can test the js code at here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gridlines are not supported for category axes. Because the data in question is using strings as the categories (X-axis labels), there is no way to tell how they "should" be split. You can get around this, however, with the following techniques.

Trick 1: Turn your Data Numerical

So right now you have strings which means no gridlines. We want gridlines though, so we have to correct that small problem. So we turn our first column (X) in to a number, with a format on it so it says 'A' or 'B' or 'C' when you mouse over it (and in the legend):

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
  data.addRows([
    [{v: 1, f:'A'},   1,       10],
    [{v: 2, f:'B'},   2,       5],
    [{v: 3, f:'C'},   4,       12],
    [{v: 4, f:'D'},   8,       5]
  ]);
```

This doesn't solve the problem though. Now we have numbers on the bottom axis, cut off at weird 0.8 intervals. So we want to fix that. Unfortunately, with the hAxis, you can't set a min/max value and have it stick (I don't know why). We can fix the min by adding baseline: 0 to our options.

To get the max, we have to add a dummy series.

Put it all together, and we get this:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
  // This dummy series is to extend the chart from 0-5 for padding
  data.addColumn('number', null);
  data.addRows([
    [{v: 1, f:'A'}, 1, 10, null],
    [{v: 2, f:'B'}, 2, 5, null],
    [{v: 3, f:'C'}, 4, 12, null],
    [{v: 4, f:'D'}, 8, 5, null],
    [{v: 5, f:''}, null, null, {v: 0, f:''}]
  ]);

  options = {
    curveType: 'function',
    lineWidth: 2,
    hAxis: {
      // Show a baseline at 0
      baseline: 0,
      // 6 Gridlines, 4 labels + left and right for padding
      gridlines: {
        count: 6
      },
    },
    vAxis: {
      baseline: 0,
    },
    series: [
      {},
      {},
      // Hide our dummy series
      {
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointsize: 0,
        visibleInLegend: false
      },
    ]
  };
  chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart1.draw(data, options);
}
```

Now it's looking more like what you want. There are two main issues. One is that if you mouseover the bottom right of the chart, a blank tooltip pops up (this is not a huge issue I'd hope, though you may have to do some error trapping if you make the chart interactive with events). The other is that the bottom of our chart is showing numbers, not letters.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to format numbers as letters (at least until Google implements the entire ICU pattern set rather than just dates/numbers). So we need to make another workaround. Basically, what I do is create an entirely new chart just to make the labels. I then format it so that it hides everything but the labels, and make sure that it lines up horizontally with the chart above.

```
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
    // This dummy series is to extend the chart from 0-5 for padding
    data.addColumn('number', null);
    data.addRows([
      [{v: 1, f:'A'}, 1, 10, null],
      [{v: 2, f:'B'}, 2, 5, null],
      [{v: 3, f:'C'}, 4, 12, null],
      [{v: 4, f:'D'}, 8, 5, null],
      [{v: 5, f:''}, null, null, {v: 0, f:''}]
    ]);

    options = {
      curveType: 'function',
      lineWidth: 2,
      hAxis: {
        // Show a baseline at 0
        baseline: 0,
        // 6 Gridlines, 4 labels + left and right for padding
        gridlines: {
          count: 6
        },
        // Hide our labels
        textPosition: 'none'
      },
      vAxis: {
        baseline: 0,
      },
      series: [
        {},
        {},
        // Hide our dummy series
        {
          lineWidth: 0,
          pointsize: 0,
          visibleInLegend: false
        },
      ]
    };

    // Add dummy data for the axis labels
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'dummy');
    data2.addRows([
      ['A', null],
      ['B', null],
      ['C', null],
      ['D', null]
    ]);

    chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart1.draw(data, options);

    chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization2'));
    chart2.draw(data2,
                {
                  chartArea: {
                    top:0,
                    height:"0%"
                  },
                  min: 0,
                  max: 0,
                  hAxis: {
                    baselineColor: '#FFFFFF'
                  },
                  vAxis: {
                    baselineColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    direction: -1,
                    textPosition: 'none',
                    gridlines: {
                      color: '#FFFFFF'
                    }
                  }
                });
  }
```

Just make another  below the first one, and use CSS to align it properly (float it around the same position, or whatnot), and it looks like the labels belong to the chart above.

It ain't glorious, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, my chart has been drawn with the grid now, however it can't show X-Axis label! :)

Comment: You need to make a second chart like I have in the third block of code that will just show the labels. Or you can add them in a different way if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more elegant solution by using `xticks`:
To do that we define a datatable like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addRows([
        [{v: 0, f:'Jan'}, 1000],
        [{v: 1, f:'Feb'}, 1170],
        [{v: 2, f:'Mar'}, 660],
        [{v: 3, f:'Apr'}, 1030]
    ]);
```

Where we set number values but also string labels for the `Month` axis.
With just this and the `format` attribute removed, we would get vertical lines but numbers instead of the strings for the x axis labels, which is not what we want.
To fix this we can set `xticks` to force the correct labels in the plot.

```
var options = {
        title: '',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Month',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#333'
            },
            baseline: 0,
            gridlines: {
                color: '#f3f3f3',
              count: 4
            },
           ticks: [{v: 0, f:'Jan'},{v: 1, f:'Feb'},{v: 2, f:'Mar'},{v: 3, f:'Apr'}], // <------- This does the trick
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            gridlines: {
                color: '#f3f3f3',
                count: 5
            }
        }
    };
```

Hereby a complete working fiddle to show you how it can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/417/

Comment: Can your suggestion above be modified to work with data.join (for 2 bar line in same graph) too , I get this error Error: Type mismatch. Value 0 does not match type string in column index 0 , I understand the error is mismatch of variable type but not very sure how to resolve this
Here is the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/534/