# Gaps in Data on Google Charts Continuous Axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart with a continuous date-time X axis. My data comes in short bursts, with long delays between the bursts. I'd like to make the Chart have a non-continuous X axis, but still have the auto-generated timestamps *during* the samples. Is that possible?

Basically, say I have 3 samples, each which have 300 datapoints, recorded across 10 second intervals, but with hour gaps between them. I'd like to have my chart show the 30 seconds of data at a zoom level where it can be distinguished. Am I stuck?

Edit: Per @jmac's suggestion, here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
1360096658270, 10.228335
1360096658274, 10.308437
1360096658277, 10.294770
[...]
1360096673968, 9.014943
1360096673969, 8.971434
1360096673970, 9.041739
1360096673971, 9.097484
^^-- 15 seconds
<--- (~10 days)
1360989176509, 9.856928
1360989176513, 9.852907
1360989176517, 9.861740
1360989176523, 9.820416
1360989176527, 9.871401
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have data like this `...__________...__________...` and you want to display it more like `..._..._...` stretched out to the same width to get a better resolution on the data without all the white space in between?

Comment: Yep, exactly. That would be perfect.

Comment: Could you give some sample data? Is it 300 points, 1 point per 10 seconds, or 300 points at random times within a 10-second span?

Comment: I edited the post to add some example data. It varies, but it's about 500 points fairly regularly within a 10-second span, and then nothing for hours or days.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I gave you three ways to do it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: Multiple Charts**

This is probably the simplest in concept (though still a hassle).

Summary:

1. Split data in to groups (eliminate the gaps)
2. Create a separate chart for each group
3. Eliminate the vAxis labels for every chart past the first
4. Create a consistent vAxis min/max value
5. Use CSS to line the charts up side to side

Details:

If you have a static data set, you can just split it by hand. If it isn't static, then you have to write some javascript to split up your data. I can't really help you here since I don't know how your data works.

As far as setting up the charts, I'll leave that up to you. I don't know how you want them formatted, so again I can't really help you with the current info.

To create a consistent axis value for all charts, you need to use some basic math in a javascript function to assign the same numbers to each vAxis max/min value. Here is a sample:

```
// Take the Max/Min of all data values in all graphs
var totalMax = 345;
var totalMin = -123;

// Figure out the largest number (positive or negative)
var biggestNumber = Math.max(Math.abs(totalMax),Math.abs(totalMin));

// Round to an exponent of 10 appropriate for the biggest number
var roundingExp = Math.floor(Math.log(biggestNumber) / Math.LN10);
var roundingDec = Math.pow(10,roundingExp);

// Round your max and min to the nearest exponent of 10
var newMax = Math.ceil(totalMax/roundingDec)*roundingDec;
var newMin = Math.floor(totalMin/roundingDec)*roundingDec;

// Determine the range of your values
var range = newMax - newMin;

// Define the number of gridlines (default 5)
var gridlines = 5;

// Determine an appropriate gap between gridlines
var interval = range / (gridlines - 1);

// Round that interval up to the exponent of 10
var newInterval = Math.ceil(interval/roundingDec)*roundingDec;

// Re-round your max and min to the new interval
var finalMax = Math.ceil(totalMax/newInterval)*newInterval;
var finalMin = Math.floor(totalMin/newInterval)*newInterval;
```

**Method 2: Multiple Series**

As long as the people viewing your data understand they are different sets, then there's no reason the axis needs to say the exact date/time as long as they can easily figure that out elsewhere.

Summary:

1. Separate your data in to different series for each 'sequence'
2. Artificially shorten the gaps between sequences (if they are 15 seconds each, then have a 5 second gap between series, or just start every 15 seconds)
3. Format each different series with a name labeling when the run started/ended

Details:

Again, you will have to split your data manually or create javascript to do it, but what you want to do is to move each set of numbers in to its own column, like so:

```
1360096658270, 10.228335, null
1360096658274, 10.308437, null
1360096658277, 10.294770, null
[...]
1360096673968, 9.014943, null
1360096673969, 8.971434, null
1360096673970, 9.041739, null
1360096673971, 9.097484, null
^^-- 15 seconds
<--- (~10 days)
1360989176509, null, 9.856928
1360989176513, null, 9.852907
1360989176517, null, 9.861740
1360989176523, null, 9.820416
1360989176527, null, 9.871401
```

This will make each series be a different color (and have a different label in the legend/on mouseover), so you can see the difference between runs, but also get a nice tooltip saying "This data was gathered from X to Y" so that if the time the data was taken is important, it's still in there (albeit not on the X axis).

These are the easiest ways.

**Method 3: Manually Editing the X-Axis Labels**

The third way is the most flexible but also takes the most work. You can create a custom javascript function to manipulate the X-axis labels in SVG. More details on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526032/google-charts-bubble-charts-categorical-x-and-y-axes-instead-of-numeric) by @jeffery_the_wind:

```
/*
 *
 * The following 2 functions are a little hacky, they have to be done after calling the "draw" function
 * The bubble chart originally displays only numbers along the x and y axes instead of customer or product names
 * These 2 functions replace those numbers with the words for the customers and products
 *
 */
for ( var i = -2; i < products.length + 1; i ++ ){
    $('#customer_product_grid svg text[text-anchor="start"]:contains("'+i+'")').text(function(j,t){
        if (t == i){
            if (i >= products.length || i < 0){
                return " ";
            }
            return products[i];
        }
    });
}

for ( var i = -2; i <= customers.length + 3; i ++ ){
    $('#customer_product_grid svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("'+i+'")').text(function(j,t){
        if (i >= customers.length + 1 || i <= 0){
            return " ";
        }else if (t == i){                    
            return customers[i-1];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh man, that is great! Thank you so much for taking the time to write all this out!

Comment: No problem -- the goal of the site is to help future generations, so I tend to give comprehensive replies when at all possible. Best of luck and let us know how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

Google's documentation on [customizing axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) describes how to do what you're asking.   You can change the type of your column to a string and populate with formatted Date strings.

Comment: Yeah, that was my fallback plan. I was hoping for something better than having to create my own axis ticks by using their continuous axis, but I will do that if I have to. Thanks!