# Google chart Swiss y-axis number format

Tags: google-visualization

Is there a way without hack how to format y-axis labels to Swiss-German style 
(ex. -> 10000000 10'000'000) ?
Tried to set language to Swiss, but it`s still not formatted as it should

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { "packages": ["corechart"], 'language': 'de_CH' })
```

Added example how exaclty I want it to be, now I hacked it, but wondering if there is a better way...

[Format Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9b9V.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible.

Google uses a subset of the [ICU DecimalFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details) set, and unfortunately this doesn't allow you to force a locale on people or change the separator. If you are getting a `.` as your separator now, that's the closest you will get.

The only way to force something like that would be to write custom code that loops through the `svg` element that the chart creates, using a custom javascript function that will replace the `.` or `,` with `'`. There is no super-easy way to do this, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526032/google-charts-bubble-charts-categorical-x-and-y-axes-instead-of-numeric) by jeffrey_the_wind shows one way:

> Judging from all the searching I did, and also the answer given here
>   by jmac, I decided the only way to go was a Javascript hack to replace
>   the axes numbers with words.  The code I implemented is here:
>
> ```
>     /*
>      *
>      * The following 2 functions are a little hacky, they have to be done after calling the "draw" function
>      * The bubble chart originally displays only numbers along the x and y axes instead of customer or product names
>      * These 2 functions replace those numbers with the words for the customers and products
>      *
>      */
>     for ( var i = -2; i < products.length + 1; i ++ ){
>         $('#customer_product_grid svg text[text-anchor="start"]:contains("'+i+'")').text(function(j,t){
>             if (t == i){
>                 if (i >= products.length || i < 0){
>                     return " ";
>                 }
>                 return products[i];
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     for ( var i = -2; i <= customers.length + 3; i ++ ){
>         $('#customer_product_grid svg text[text-anchor="end"]:contains("'+i+'")').text(function(j,t){
>             if (i >= customers.length + 1 || i <= 0){
>                 return " ";
>             }else if (t == i){                    
>                 return customers[i-1];
>             }
>         });
>     }
> ```
>
> Basically, you just make a for loop that iterates through all the
>   integers that you are showing on the x and y axes.  Do some
>   `if...else` stuff to either replace the integer with an element from
>   the array, or just make it blank.
>
> Keep in mind for the above code to work properly, you need to have the
>   following property in the chart options -> `vAxis: { textPosition:
>   'in' }`

Answer (score 0):

Here`s my hack

```
//Format diagram y-axis labels
    var labelContainer = $($("#diagramPlaceholder").find("g")[1]).children("g:last-child").children("g");

    //Foreach x,y1,y2 labels do
    labelContainer.each(function() {
        var textContainer = $(this).find("text");
        //If labels contains valid number
        if (!isNaN(textContainer.text().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'))) {
            //Replace " . " chars with " ' " char
            textContainer.text(textContainer.text().replace(/\b[.]\b/g, '\''));
        }
    });
```