# gvisBubbleChart with categories for shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, google-visualization

I'm looking for a versatile bubble chart. 
In my shiny app it has to be able to adjust to two things:

1. It must be clickable. I need to read the selected bubble from the chart and use the selected input for other visualisations inside the app.
2. I have a categorial x-axis.

I was looking into gvisBubbleChart which seemed to fit very well, but it only responds to a numerical x-axis.

For example:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),xvar = c("a","b","c","d","e"),yvar = c(7,2,5,8,1),sizevar = c(3,66,7,8,5),colorvar = rep(0,5))

plot(gvisBubbleChart(data,idvar = "id", xvar = "xvar", yvar = "yvar", sizevar = "sizevar",colorvar="colorvar"))
```

Changes the xaxis to 1.5:6.0 instead of the string.

Is there a way to work around this? It seems that the input has to be numerical, I could not find a native option to turn this off.

I'm also very open to any other suggested packages which serve my needs, for ggplot I'm not sure if I can make the clickable part work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked various sources, editing the googlevisBubble chart is possible with a lot of effort, too much for my case as this would be a very hard workaround.

[Google Charts Bubble Charts categorical x and y axes instead of numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526032/google-charts-bubble-charts-categorical-x-and-y-axes-instead-of-numeric)

What I'm going to do is use plotly with ggplot for the dynamic input in my shiny app, the hole package looks very promising.

https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-plotly-events/