# How to display both horizontal and vertical grid lines in google chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004', 1000, 400],
          ['2005', 1170, 460],
          ['2006', 660, 1120],
          ['2007', 1030, 540]
      ]);

      var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

this code only shows horizontal grid line, I want to show vertical lines also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `vAxis.gridlines` and `hAxis.gridlines` in [these docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

`vAxis.gridlines` is an object with properties to configure the gridlines on the vertical axis. To specify properties of this object, you can use object literal notation, as shown here:

```
 {color: '#333', count: 4}
```

You can use the following in your options for the vertical gridlines:

```
vAxis.gridlines: {color: '#333', count: 4}
```

**EDIT**: 
See these examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/R4DGp/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/8eCSW/1/

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: will you please add a complete example.

Comment: @DeveloperSuRu [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14274651/586051) might also be helpful to you.

Comment: if we user linechart instead of corechart its not showing vertical grid

Comment: @DeveloperSuRu Where are we using corechart anyway? Can you please create a fiddle of your chart so I can help you better?

Comment: Here it is.. http://jsfiddle.net/qsaehvje/3/
  Help me draw vertical lines for this chart